# invalid encoding name UTF8 when gradle build

Tags: linux, gradle, encoding

I download the cas(https://github.com/apereo/cas.git) source code and try to build it with gradle. I got a Exception like this error:

> Could not resolve org.apache.shiro:shiro-root:1.2.5
>   Could not parse POM http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/shiro/shiro-root/1.2.5/shiro-root-1.2.5.pom
>   Invalid encoding name "UTF8".

I run locale :

```
 LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8 
 LANGUAGE=zh_CN:zh:en_US:en 
 LC_CTYPE=zh_CN.UTF-8
 LC_NUMERIC=zh_CN.UTF-8 
 LC_TIME=zh_CN.UTF-8 
 LC_COLLATE="zh_CN.UTF-8"
 LC_MONETARY=zh_CN.UTF-8 
 LC_MESSAGES="zh_CN.UTF-8" 
 LC_PAPER=zh_CN.UTF-8
 LC_NAME=zh_CN.UTF-8 
 LC_ADDRESS=zh_CN.UTF-8 
 LC_TELEPHONE=zh_CN.UTF-8
 LC_MEASUREMENT=zh_CN.UTF-8 
 LC_IDENTIFICATION=zh_CN.UTF-8 
 LC_ALL=
```

and locale -l

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
zh_CN.gb18030
zh_CN.gb2312
zh_CN.gbk
zh_CN.utf8
zh_HK.utf8
zh_SG.utf8
zh_TW.utf8
```

I have try set the lcoale to zh_CN.UTF8 in .profile file . It works fine in bash but same error in gradle build

what should I do ??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
tasks.withType(Compile) {
 options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Comment: Struggling the same thing without actually knowing the gradle... In recent gradle builds its supposed to be JavaCompile and not Compile, but when I do that, the same error remains...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Shiro 1.2.5 was misconfigured. https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@shiro.apache.org/msg03201.html

`cas` now uses version 1.4.0, so an upgrade should fix your issue. https://github.com/apereo/cas/blob/1a57c688b3d698d35c4171ac67d056442f6e5628/gradle.properties#L162